# SQL Query using where with multi option

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

im trying to write down a query to filter data in SFMC but it seems there is something wrong please I need help
query :

```
Select
Email,
phone,
LastName,
FirstName
From [sendable] C

Where phone = ('2345456464', 
'65465656',
'6456656456',
'656546546',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IN operator for this

```
SELECT Email, Phone, LastName, FirstName 
FROM [Your_Object] 
WHERE Phone IN ('2345456464', '65465656', '6456656456', '656546546')
```

Plus you made a little typo: please remove the last comma after the closing paranthesis

Below is an information from the source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm

If the value equals any one of the values in a WHERE clause, use IN. For example:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Account
WHERE BillingState IN ('California', 'New York')
```

The values for IN must be in parentheses. String values must be surrounded by single quotes.

You can also use IN and NOT IN for semi-joins and anti-joins when querying on ID (primary key) or reference (foreign key) fields.

Comment: thank you so much